# How to enter into BIOS with external monitor?

Tags: display, bios

My laptop screen is broken and I have only HDMI port and a monitor. I was unable to go to bios. I tried several ways but nothing worked.

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
- 4GB ram
- HP notebook, Windows 11
- Monitor Dell 1908WFP

Answer (score 1):

BIOS works outside of Windows or other operating system.

Most (not all) BIOS have no capability to use an external monitor, so you will need to fix your screen.

Some (not many) BIOS may possibly have the ability to use an external monitor, but you would need to check the BIOS to see.

Summary:  Fix your screen to update BIOS.